# A question about a perfect space and a linear order on it

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a nonempty perfect Polish space $X$, and there's some linear order $<$ on it (it is not related to the topology on $X$ in any way). How can I prove that there is a point $y$ in $X$ such that $y\in \overline{\{x\in X|x < y}\}\cap \overline{\{x\in X|x > y\}}$? Hints would be very much appreciated (please if it's possible don't post full answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Assume not. Show that without loss of generality there is an uncountable $A\subseteq X$ such that each $x\in A$ has an open nbhd $U_x\subseteq(\leftarrow,x]$. Then recall that a separable metric space is second countable.

Comment: Aha, so it goes like that: assume the contrary. Hence for each point $x$ I can choose $U_x$ (from a fixed countable base of $X$) such that $U_x\cap (\leftarrow, x]$ is empty or $U_x\cap (x, \rightarrow]$ is empty. Since my space is uncountable (being perfect Polish), one of the conditions holds for an uncountable subset $A$ of $X$. Say the first one. But then since the number of different $U_x$ was countable, there is $U_{x_0}$ which contains infinitely many points from $A$ (apart from $x_0$). Take any $x\in A\backslash \{x_0\}$. Then by construction $x < x_0$ but also $U_{x_0}$ is its [...]

Comment: [...] open neighborhood which was supposed to be contained in $(\leftarrow,x]$, a contradiction.

Comment: @C_M: Yep; looks good.

Comment: Thank you! (but I see I've confused one thing, I'm in fact assuming that the second condition holds (in the beginning), and in the first condition the closing bracket should be ")" instead of "]"... But I've got the idea! :) ) Thank you very much again!

Comment: @C_M: You're very welcome!